# BufferedReader.readLine() hangs sometimes

Tags: java, apache, rss, httpclient, bufferedreader

In my application, there is a separate thread, ran by `ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate()` every minute, which parses rss feeds from multiple websites. I am using Apache HttpClient to receive xml.

Sample code:

```
InputStream inputStream = HTTPClient.get(url);    
String xml = inputStreamToString(inputStream, encoding, websiteName);

public static String inputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream, String encoding, String websiteName) 
{

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    PrintWriter printWriter = null;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    int letter;
    try 
    {
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, encoding));
        printWriter = new PrintWriter(new File("src/doclog/" 
                + websiteName + "_" 
                + new SimpleDateFormat("MM_dd_yyyy_hh_mm_ss").format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())) 
                + "_" + encoding + ".txt"), encoding);
        while((letter = bufferedReader.read()) != -1) 
        {
            char character = (char) letter;
            printWriter.print(character);               
            stringBuilder.append(character);
        }
    } 
    catch(IOException e) 
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } 
    finally
    {
        try 
        {
            if(bufferedReader != null) 
            {
                bufferedReader.close();
            }
            if(printWriter != null) 
            {
                printWriter.close();
            }
        } 
        catch(IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("String built");
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

And HTTPClient class:

```
public class HTTPClient 
{
   private static final HttpClient CLIENT = HttpClientBuilder.create().build(); 

   public static InputStream get(String url)
   {    
       try
       {
           HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);  
           HttpResponse response = CLIENT.execute(request);
           System.out.println("Response Code: " + response.getStatusLine().toString()); 
           return response.getEntity().getContent();
       }
       catch(IOException | IllegalArgumentException e)
       {
           throw new RuntimeException(e);
       }
   }
}
```

As the title says, sometimes there is a chance that `bufferedReader.readLine()` will hang forever. I've seen another answers on this topic, and they suggest to check if `bufferedReader.ready()` returns `true`. The problem is that there are websites, which will always return `false` in `bufferedReader.ready()`, while processing them, however they parse just fine.

How can i prevent my thread from hanging on bufferedReader.readLine()?

If it matters, `response.getStatusLine().toString()` always returns `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`

**EDIT**

I just found out that `bufferedReader.ready()` is actually `true` when hang happens.

**EDIT 2**

`BufferedReader.read()` hangs as well. It is strange that hang happens only when dealing with one single website, and it's occurrence is absolutely random. Application either could be working for 15 hours, receiving hundreds of non-problematic responses, or hang just in 10 minutes after launch. I've started to write all characters of every single update into separate file, and found out that nothing special really happens. Xml reading simply stops forever in the middle of document, the last characters were `&lt;p dir=&quot;ltr&quot;&g`. Updated the code.

Also, it's noteworthy to mention that there can't be any unhandled exceptions, because at the highest level of my `ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate()` runnable i catch `Throwable`, and print it's stackTrace.

Answer (score 3):

The `ready()` method returns `true` telling you that there are characters available for reading. The problem is that `readLine()` blocks until it finds an end-of-line in the input.

> public String readLine()
>                   throws IOException
>
> Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one
>   of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return
>   followed immediately by a linefeed.

As you are reading from a stream there is no guarantee that the data will come in at line boundaries so the `readLine()` call blocks.

You can use the `read` method which will not block, but you will have to check for EOL yourself.

> public int read(char[] cbuf, int off, int len) throws IOException
>
> Reads characters into a portion of an array.
>
> This method implements the general contract of the corresponding read
>   method of the Reader class. As an additional convenience, it attempts
>   to read as many characters as possible by repeatedly invoking the read
>   method of the underlying stream. This iterated read continues until
>   one of the following conditions becomes true:
>
> ```
> The specified number of characters have been read,
> The read method of the underlying stream returns -1, indicating end-of-file, or
> The ready method of the underlying stream returns false, indicating that further input requests would block.
> ```
>
> If the first read on the underlying stream returns -1 to indicate
>   end-of-file then this method returns -1. Otherwise this method returns
>   the number of characters actually read.

Also you will have to reconstruct the line from the characters read. It is not ss convenient as reading the entire line at once but it is the way it must be done.

Comment: Could it be a problem with encoding? So `readLine()` can't recognize EOLs.

Comment: @DaSH I don't think so. EOL is standard. If readLine did not recognize EOLs it would keep reading forever and you would have a bigger problem since the line variable would use a lot of memory and you  would end with garbage in the string.

Comment: Changed the code to `while((letter = bufferedReader.read()) != -1) `, looks like it's working ok now. Thankfully i don't really need to separate lines.

Comment: Holy crap, it still freezes from time to time. Looks like sometimes `bufferedReader.read()` never equals `-1`. What could be the case?

Comment: @DaSH Could you post your updated code? -1 should indicate EOF, but since you are not reading from an actual file EOF means something different. At least you should get an exception. Does it get blocked forever or it continues after some time?

Comment: It is possible that you are facing some threading issue. There are files or variables that are shared by your threads? For example, StringBuilder is not thread safe as most of the classes you are using in your sample code.

Comment: Well, i don't think so. Because method `inputStreamToString()` is called only inside one thread, and hang happens specificially in that method, on line `letter = bufferedReader.read()`. Infinite `while` loop definitely isn't the case, at some point just method `bufferedReader.read()` is never done. I am worried by the fact that my program handles about 15 RSS urls, and the only problematic website is this one. At the beginning there were also problems with encoding, which caused `SAXBuilder` to crash, so i began using Apache HttpClient, which kinda removed all these exceptions.

Comment: If it happens with only one of the URLs it may be the case that the server is misbehaving. Usually, when the server has done sending the data it closes the connection immediately or after a fraction of a second as directed by the Connection header. Can you check if it hangs after receiving all the expected content or in the middle of the data? Also check if the connection is still open when it hangs. I suspect EOF occurs when the connection is closed by the server. Maybe you will have to close the connection at the client side.